# Background of the Hasagat HaRa'avad on Rambam

Tags: words, jewish-books, rambam

A few questions about the Ra'avad:

1. What does Hasagat mean in the context of the title of Hasagat HaRa'avad?
   I have seen the term used in reference to his works "HaRa'avad BeHasagatsv" So it sounds like hasaga is a literary genre of it's own. Are there any other 'Hasagot'
2. Does the Ra'avad have other works as well?
3. Was it written by the Ra'avad on the Rambam or was it created based on his other works by a third party.

Comment: Rabad of Posquieres: A Twelfth-Century Talmudist https://a.co/d/4q5mc5T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your questions

1. A hasagah is a refutation or attack or question. So Hasagot HaRa'avad would mean the attacks of the Ra'avad on the positions of the Rambam. Other authors created Hasagot like Hasagot HaRamban on the Sefer HaMitzvos of the Rambam. The Ra'avad also made Hasagot on the Ba'al HaMeor on the Rif.
2. He had a commentary on the entirety of the Talmud, but we don't have it as far as I know. other Rishonim quote from it, such as the Ramban and Rashba et. al. I already referenced his comments on the Ba'al HaMeor
3. It was written by the Ra'avad himself as short comments on the Rambam's work which had just been released at the time.

Comment: I know we have the commentary of Raavad to Bava Kamma and Avodah Zarah. There could be others I'm not aware of.

Comment: Worth noting that when Ramban quotes Raavad (as הרב אב״ד) it can also be Raavad II, the father-in-law of Raavad III who is the subject of this question.

Comment: He also wrote stand-alone halachic works, perhaps most famously Baalei Hanefesh (on Niddah) and Hilkhot Lulav (on, surprise, Lulav)

Comment: Not all the hasagot are attacks or questions. Twersky did a good analysis in his biography.